# CoreData Crash While fetching Error: NSProcessingInternalChange

Tags: ios, core-data

In my application I am saving data to coredata in the main thread\queue and immediately after save, I fetch all the records to make sure I have not exceeded the size of my local store.

All happens on synchronously on the main thread.

I get random crashes:

> [NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2284

The core data has attributes indexed and I am wondering if the index generation happens after save returns and fetch catches the database during indexing and fails?

Also I see another thread `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

What does this mean? I specifically send the coredata operations to be executed in main thread. Does coredata internally send it to another thread?

What could be causing the crash here? Would appreciate any help!

The stack trace looks like this:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018214602c __CFBasicHashDrain + 196
1  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182145f9c __CFBasicHashDrain + 52
2  CoreData                       0x0000000181de28c8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2284
3  CoreData                       0x0000000181ddadc4 _performRunLoopAction + 384
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820cc2a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
5  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820c9230 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
6  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820c9610 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
7  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181ff52d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
8  GraphicsServices               0x000000018b80b6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
9  UIKit                          0x0000000186bbafac UIApplicationMain + 1488
10 MyApp                     0x000000010002ba88 main (main.m:16)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000193fb6a08 start + 4

Thread : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x170666900
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x00000001941616a4 OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier + 12
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000194169428 _pthread_mutex_lock + 312
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193c89d0c (null) + 20676
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193cb30ec (null) + 20388
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193cb27ac (null) + 18020
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193cb255c (null) + 17428
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193c85688 (null) + 2624
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193caccf0 (null) + 56216
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x0000000193c9f368 sqlite3_step + 528
9  CoreData                       0x0000000181db47e8 _execute + 124
10 CoreData                       0x0000000181dc5574 -[NSSQLiteConnection fetchResultSet:usingFetchPlan:] + 1664
11 CoreData                       0x0000000181ec48f4 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1544
12 CoreData                       0x0000000181dcf4bc -[NSSQLCore fetchRowForObjectID:] + 1080
13 CoreData                       0x0000000181dcedc0 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 280
14 CoreData                       0x0000000181e89524 __95-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 76
15 CoreData                       0x0000000181e90028 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 184
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f89954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f931e4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 76
18 CoreData                       0x0000000181e81e98 _perform + 180
19 CoreData                       0x0000000181dcebf0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 160
20 CoreData                       0x0000000181dce210 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow +    352
21 CoreData                       0x0000000181dcdc84 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 252
22 CoreData                       0x0000000181dcda70 _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 116
23 CoreData                       0x0000000181dde638 _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty + 176
24 Foundation                     0x0000000182f2c7c4 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 384
25 Foundation                     0x0000000182f6a94c -[NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 608
26 CoreData                       0x0000000181dba32c -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 3796
27 MyApp                     0x00000001001b2b2c static MyApp.CacheHelper.fetchCacheEntriesInAscendingOrderByAccess (MyApp.CacheHelper.Type)(Swift.String) -> Swift.Optional<Swift.Array<Swift.AnyObject>> (CacheHelper.swift:155)
28 MyApp                     0x0000000100145ee8 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of MyApp.Base.controlCapacity (MyApp.Base)() -> () (Base.swift:45)
29 MyApp                     0x00000001001450a0 MyApp.Base.controlCapacity (MyApp.Base)() -> () (Base.swift)
30 MyApp                     0x0000000100145c74 MyApp.Base.setCacheEntryInternal (MyApp.Base)(MyApp.CacheEntry) -> () (Base.swift:120)
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f89994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f89954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f940a4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1448
34 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f8ca5c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132

35 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f96318 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
36 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193f97c4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
37 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019416922c _pthread_wqthread + 816`
```